# Tortoise SVN deleted folders keep coming back

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have a number of projects in my repository that are no longer needed.

I removed them from the repository - this seemed to remove them from SVN control as the relevant icons in Windows Explorer went away and the folders now show as standard Windows folders.

I then deleted the items from the hard disk.

Imagine my suprise to find when I went into the folder the next day, all of the deleted folders back. So I deleted them again - and they came back again.

None of them are showing as under source control.

What am I doing wrong??

Comment: Have you deleted the folders and commited the change?

Comment: Now the folders are showing as standard windows folders I dont have an option to commit the change. Should my parent folder be under source control which would allow that to happen?

Comment: This sounds weird. Without issuing an SVN command the folders don't just come back over night. So the question is, if you don't use SVN, do you restore the folders from the trash can or some other file system restore? Or did you forget to mention that the folders come back after an SVN update?

Comment: Hi, its when I just browse the folder. They re-appear but not under SVN contorl. Last time I CTRL+Deleted them so they didnt go into the trash can. I deleted them last night but tonight when I use the computer again they will just appear. 
Maybe what I can do is put them back into SVN and then use the SVN delete command. Before I just removed from the repository and then just deleted from the disk.

Comment: How did you delete the files from the repository? When I mark a file for deletion from SVN using Tortoise (Right click on file, Tortoise SVN -> Delete) it is removed in Windows Explorer immediately. I don't have to manually delete the file once I've committed the change.

Comment: What kind of files are these? Certain system files on Windows underlie protection, i.e.if you try to delete/modify them, the original version is going to be restored. The same holds for files installed with an MSI installer. MSI is protecting the installation and as soon as the installed executable is started, any missing file is reinstalled. Could it be any of those?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the repository browser to check whether those folders really are deleted in the repository.

But I assume they are not. Most likely you just deleted the folders in your explorer. You must use the "Delete" command from the TSVN menu to remove folders from version control and then commit that deletion.

Comment: Hi, they are definately removed from the repository. Ive just checked in Visual SVN Server.

Comment: I had the same problem. I deleted the folder from within the repository browser, yet when I do an update in my working copy, it comes back. I don't know why. Eventually I completely deleted the working copy, and then remade it and it was gone

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem, deleted a folder with SVN. It reappeared as unversioned.

It was because the folder was still in my visual studio project file. After deleting it there, e

Answer (score 1):

Did you commit the delete?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably referencing a previous revision number where those folders still existed.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Delete the files from the repo using TortoiseSVN. Checked again and again, the files were deleted. I even tested from another computer. Every time I updated the files came back.

**The solution** for me was to restart the SVN server and the problem went away and so did the files.